# Prove that $B\cap \bar{A}$ and $(B\cap \bar{A^c})$ are open sets.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $X$ be a metric space and $A\subseteq X$. Show that every connected subset $B$ such that $B\cap A\neq\emptyset $ and $B\cap A^c\neq\emptyset$ where $A^c$ is the complement of $A$, then $B \cap \partial  A\neq\emptyset$.

**My try:** Suppose that $B \cap\partial  A=\varnothing$. Then $(B\cap \bar{A})\cap (B\cap \overline{A^c})=\varnothing$ and $$B=(B\cap A)\cup (B\cap A^c)$$
I would need to prove that $B\cap \bar{A}$ and $B\cap \overline{A^c}$ are open, so that they form a separation of the set $B$ and contradict that $B$ is connected, some help for that.

Comment: What does $FrA$ mean?

Comment: the boundary of a set @diracdeltafunk

Comment: Thanks -- this is not standard notation (in English at least), so it would be good to add it to your post. A more usual notation would be $\partial A$.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'll put it the other way then. @diracdeltafunk

Comment: Hint: since $\overline{A}$ is closed, $B \cap \overline{A}$ is closed in $B$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: I think it is pretty standard. It's one of the three noted in the opening paragraph on Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind with the hint is that $C\cap \overline{A^c}$ matches $C-(C\cap \bar{A})$ which is open, but they don't match because it would be $ C\cap \overline{A}^c$ @diracdeltafunk

Comment: @tomasz Oh, good to know! I somehow have gotten this far without ever seeing this notation (or if I have I've subsequently forgotten :p). Apologies, James!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I guess that it is more standard the notation $\partial A$, the notation $Fr(A)$ is used in spanish because in spanish boundary=frontera, so it makes sense the $Fr$, but I have never seen it used in english texts.

Comment: *Frontière* in French. So $\operatorname{Fr}(A)$ is also standard in French.

Comment: The opening paragraph on Wikipedia also contains a discussion about the terminology boundary vs border vs frontier in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $A$ we have that $$X = \operatorname{int}(A) \cup \partial A \cup X\setminus \overline{A}$$ and this is a disjoint union of two open sets (the interior and the complement of the closure) and one closed set (the boundary). This is simply because for any $x \in X$ either it has a neighbourhood inside $A$ (then $x \in \operatorname{int}(A)$, **or** a neighbourhood missing $A$ entirely (then $x \in X\setminus \overline{A}$) **or** *every* neighbourhood intersects both $A$ and its complement, making it a point of $\partial A$, and these options are exhaustive and mutually exclusive.

**If** $B \cap \partial A = \emptyset$ while $B \cap A$ and $B \cap A^\complement$ are non-empty, it follows that

$$B = (B \cap \operatorname{int}(A)) \cup B \cap (X\setminus \overline{A})$$

is a (relatively) open partition of $B$ into two non-empty subsets. This cannot happen by connectedness. So $B \cap \partial A$ is non-empty as claimed.

That's all of the proof.